# Controls created for realization many-to-many relationship in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have read in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798514.aspx) that in Sharepoint 2010 developer can realize many-to-many relationships betwen lists using intermidiate list and sme custom logic.

Could you recomend me some already created controls for this porpose?

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want controls to do?  As the article states, the method is simply to have two lists, and a third with a lookup to each of those two lists.  You create items normally in those two lists and then create another item to link pairs of existing items.  You can either do all of this manually using OOB controls, or you can make a custom page (or pages) that will be used to create both an item and to link it as well.  Note that in sharepoint you also have the option of using multi-valued lookups.  This will perform slower, and have less options when querying the data, but it does make entering the data using OOB webparts easier.

All that said, we can't really help you much without knowing what you're looking for.